# Unable to use Flask

Tags: python, module, flask

I basically used the install command "$pip install Flask" and when I try to run a program it says "module can't be found." Flask is installed in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" but I thought the point of pip was so I could import these packages everywhere. I'm trying to run a file on my desktop and even when I move the Flask folder to the desktop, it doesn't work. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that it is on your python path. Open your interpreter and type `>>> import sys    
>>> print sys.path`.  You should see `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"` in the list that is printed

Comment: Do you have more than one installation of python on your computer?

Comment: When I print path out "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages'" comes out

Comment: Is that where flask was installed?  If not you're going to want to move flask there, or figure out why pip is installing to the wrong directory

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly solve whatever problem you are having with path variables, but one alternative would to download [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Flask actually has a good tutorial on how to accomplish this [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/#virtualenv)